# Is there any ksoap2 libaray for support every or more android versions?

Tags: java, php, android

I currently working on android application and there is a webservice call. I used 'ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar' library. it is successfully working on some android versions like 2.1.. But it is not work on android 4.0 / API level '14' and some other versions . Can anyone know any ksoap2 library wich works for every android version. Or different method to call webservice which is support for more android versions. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in every version.But you have to use asynch task to handle the network operations in 4.0 or hogher versions of android.Othervise it will raise NetworkOnMainThread Exception.